# A sentence with too many commas

Tags: meaning, punctuation, commas, sentence

Can someone please explain the following sentence?

> This perspective provides a primarily pragmatic justification, therefore, for confidentiality, in that any perceived limitations to, or undermining of, confidentiality will tend to adversely affect the quality of the therapy being provided.

The sentence is taken from a journal article related to counselling and psychotherapy. The commas are in the right positions according to the article.

Comment: Basically, the sentence tells you more or less the following:

> If there seems to be less confidentiality, the quality of the therapy will be less. Because of that, the (aforementioned) perspective is a good argument for confidentiality.

Comment: Verbosity, and arthritic English, in scientific journals is a modern plague. Why couldn't they have said simply: 'This perspective demonstrates that confidentiality is essential to the therapy'?

Answer (score 3):

"Therefore" is a parenthetical, and so is "or undermining of". Take them both out, and you are left with just one comma that is entirely justified:

> This perspective provides a primarily pragmatic justification for confidentiality, in that any perceived limitations to confidentiality will tend to adversely affect the quality of the therapy being provided.

Answer (score 0):

RegDwight correctly reduces the sentence to its essential parts (and punctuation) after withdrawing the two parenthetical elements. But in asking what the sentence means, you may be asking how the sentence might be reconstructed to convey all of the ideas of the original with fewer parenthetical breaks. To do that, we need to reinstate the ideas conveyed by "therefore" (which means something like "because of the preceding argument") and "or undermining of" (which identifies in truncated form a second potential source of adverse effects on "the quality of the therapy being provided"). One way to proceed is to reframe the sentence as follows:

> Therefore, this perspective provides a primarily pragmatic justification for confidentiality, in that any perceived limitations to confidentiality will tend to adversely affect the quality of the therapy being provided, as will any undermining of confidentiality.

This formulation yields a sentence with three commas—exactly midway between the original sentence's five and RegDwight's one. Whether it is any easier to understand than the original is a matter for each reader to decide.